# How to find all possible paths from (a, b) to (c, d) in an A[m×n] matrix?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have an m×n matrix with starting index (a, b). We have to reach the position (c, d) either by moving up, down, right or left to the adjacent element. How can we explore all possible paths?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void printPathTPtoBR(int *mat, int i, int j, int m, int n, int *path, int pi) {
   if (i == m - 1) {
      for (int k = j; k < n; k++)
         path[pi + k - j] = *((mat + i*n) + k);
      for (int l = 0; l < pi + n - j; l++)
         cout << path[l] << " ";
         cout << endl;
      return;
   }
   if (j == n - 1) {
      for (int k = i; k < m; k++)
         path[pi + k - i] = *((mat + k*n) + j);
      for (int l = 0; l < pi + m - i; l++)
         cout << path[l] << " ";
         cout << endl;
      return;
   }
   path[pi] = *((mat + i*n) + j);
   printPathTPtoBR(mat, i+1, j, m, n, path, pi + 1);
   printPathTPtoBR(mat, i, j+1, m, n, path, pi + 1);
}
void findPath(int *mat, int m, int n) {
   int *path = new int[m+n];
   printPathTPtoBR(mat, 0, 0, m, n, path, 0);
}
int main() {
   int mat[2][3] = {
      {1, 2, 3},
      {4, 5, 6}
   };
   cout<<"Path from top-left to bottom-rigth of matrix are :\n";
   findPath(*mat, 2, 3);
   return 0;
}
```

I want to move from any cell to another, moving right, left, up, down.
Here I can't move up and left

Comment: Your statement of the problem is incomplete -- as it is, the only clue we get to your real meaning is the last sentence "Here I can't move up and left". Can you make this explicit? I think all you need to say is that all paths must be as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use backtracking.

Maintain a list of visited cells.
From each cell, you have 4 possible options at best. Whenever you pick one of them, push that new cell into the list of visited cell. Recurse from the new cell. After you have exhausted all the paths from the new cell and come back to the current one, pop that new cell from the list of visited cells and push in the next possible option.

The base condition will be when you visit the target cell. Print/Save the list of visited cells when you reach there and return.